# matplotlib line that follows point

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to make line that follows points. Shadow of move. 
Something like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEjZd-AvPco
Pastebin with code: https://pastebin.com/AkHaEM4i

Everything is in the link, so I can't add some more details. Gonna paste lorem ipsum...
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
class DoublePendulum:
    def __init__(self,
                init_state = [120,0,-20,0],
                L1 = .5,
                L2 = .5, 
                M1 = 1.0, 
                M2 = 2.0, 
                G = 9.8,
                origin=(0,0)):
        self.init_state = np.asarray(init_state,dtype='float')
        self.params = (L1,L2,M1,M2,G)
        self.origin = origin
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.state = self.init_state * np.pi/180

    def position(self):
        (L1, L2, M1, M2, G) = self.params
        x = np.cumsum([self.origin[0],
                        L1 * sin(self.state[0]),
                        L2 * sin(self.state[2])])
        y = np.cumsum([self.origin[1],
                        -L1 * cos(self.state[0]),
                        -L2 * cos(self.state[2])])
        return (-x,-y)


    def dstate_dt(self,state,t):
        (M1,M2,L1,L2,G)=self.params
        dydx = np.zeros_like(state)
        dydx[0] = state[1]
        dydx[2] = state[3]

        cos_delta = cos(state[2] - state[0])
        sin_delta = sin(state[2] - state[0])

        den1 = (M1 + M2)  * L1 - M2 * L1 * cos_delta * cos_delta
        dydx[1] = (M2 * L1 * state[1] * state[1] * sin_delta * cos_delta
                + M2 * G * sin(state[2]) * cos_delta
                + M2 * L2 * state[3] * state[3] * sin_delta 
                - (M1+M2) * G * sin(state[0])) / den1
        den2 = (L2 / L1) * den1
        dydx[3] = (-M2 * L2 * state[3] * state[3] * sin_delta * cos_delta
                + (M1 + M2) * G * sin(state[0]) * cos_delta
                - (M1 + M2) * L1 * state[1] * state[1] * sin_delta
                - (M1 + M2) * G * sin(state[2])) / den2

        return dydx
    def step(self,dt):
        self.state = integrate.odeint(self.dstate_dt, self.state, [0,dt])[1]
        self.time_elapsed += dt

pendulum = DoublePendulum([120.,0.0,180.,0.0],.5,.5,10,10,10)
dt = 1./30 #fps
fig = plt.figure(1)
lim1,lim2 = 2,-2


ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False,
                    xlim=(lim1,lim2),ylim=(lim1,lim2),alpha=0.5)

ax.grid()
line, = ax.plot([],[],'o-',lw=2)
time_text = ax.text(0.02,0.95,'', transform=ax.transAxes)


def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    time_text.set_text('')

    return line, time_text

def animate(i):
    global pendulum, dt
    pendulum.step(dt)
    line.set_data(*pendulum.position())
    time_text.set_text('time = %.1f' % pendulum.time_elapsed)

    return line, time_text

from time import time
t0 = time()
animate(0)
t1 = time()
interval = 100 * dt - (t1-t0)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=150,
                            interval=interval, blit=True, init_func=init)

fig.set_size_inches(6.5, 6.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the referred youtube-video uses code very similiar to the code I published here:
https://github.com/jonas37/double_pendulum/